# About equivalent norms on a vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

**Definition.** A norm $\|\cdot\|$ in a vector space $X$ is said to be equivalent to a norm $\|\cdot\|_0$ on $X$ if there are positive numbers $a$ and $b$ such that for all $x \in X$ we have

$$ a\| x \|_0 \leq \|x\| \leq b\|x\|_0 $$

**My question**. If two norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|_{0}$ on a vector space $X$ are equivalent, then $\|x_{n} - x\| \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\|x_n - x\|_0 \rightarrow 0$.

I know that two equivalents norms induce same the topology. How can I use it to prove the sentence.

Ref: (Kreyszig) Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications.

Comment: What is the definition of equivalent norms that you are using? If posed in the right way the proof is really short.

Comment: Yes to both questions. For the first one, look up the topological definition of convergence. For the second one, that's the definition of convergence. ($x_n \to x$)

Comment: @UmbertoP. I put the definition in the question.

Comment: @NigelOvermars How can I use (1) and (2) to answer my question?

Comment: What is your question? (1) and (2) obviously answer your question provided your question is what you say **your question** is. (1) is precisely the definition of convergence. You are saying $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in the topology induced by the norm $||\cdot||$ if and only if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ in the topology induced by the norm $||\cdot||_0$.

Comment: I erase the extra information. My question is how can I prove the sentence using (if is posible) the fact that two equivalents norms induce the same topology. @D1X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the definition of convergence for Topological Spaces. Since you are dealing with norms and every norm induces a metric you may use:

> For a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \subset X$, $x_n  \to x$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $n_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq n_{\varepsilon}$ $x_n \in B(x, \varepsilon)$, where $B(x, \varepsilon)$ represents the open ball centered on $x$ and of radius $\varepsilon$.

If both norms induce the same topology over $X$ then the result follows.

Let's suppose $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$. If $x_n \to x$ in $\mathcal{T}_2$ then, as every open ball in $\mathcal{T}_1$ is an open ball in $\mathcal{T}_2$ then $x_n \to x$ in $\mathcal{T}_1$.

Recall that equivalent topologies means $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$ and  $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1$ (i.e.  $\mathcal{T}_1 =\mathcal{T}_2$).